# Computing a series using the $p$-adic norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

For my research, I am interested in studying the series $$M_{k,D}^{(p)}(x)=\sum_{M=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p^{Mk}}\sum_{\substack{a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}\\p\nmid gcd(a,b,c)\\b^2-4ac=Dp^{2M}\\a<0<Q(x)}}(ax^2+bx+c)^k$$ If $k$ is an integer, then there is nothing to do this series diverges in the euclidean norm. If we look at the convergence with respect to the $p$-adic norm by considering $M_{k,D}^{(p)}$ as a function on $\mathbb{Q}$, then the series should converge for all $k<0$. My question is : Is there any efficient way to compute the p-adic value of this series ?
Here I am interested in $D=0,1mod(4)$ not a square where $p$ is a prime number and $Q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. When I say $Q(x)>0$ I mean for a fix $x$ I consider only those quadratics that are positive at $x$. I am not too comfortable with $p$-adic techniques so any help would be helpful !

Comment: What do you mean by "upper bound" and "exact upper bound" for a $p$-adic series? And what by $D=0,1[4]$? And what by $0 < Q(x)$, given that $x$ seems to be a variable?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Just edited, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: What is the meaning of this series, ie. what is it useful for ? And it doesn't converge, add $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ (the convergence is not obvious to me even in that case, why not add $a=1$  ?)

Comment: @reuns Just edited some stuff. This series is somehow related to p-adic L-functions, modular forms and I am investigating this relation. I've computed a few cases and in fact this series does not convege for k in Z in the euclidean norm. However for k negative this should converge to some p-adic number. I would like to know if there is a way to compute it explicitely or to "average" it.